# Negative property default does not seem to work

Tags: delphi, properties, numbers, default

When I install the component, I look in the object inspector and the value for `StoppingCount` is 0!  I need the value to be -1.  In my code, anything above -1 will stop the for loop process at that number.

Does `default` not work for negative numbers?

```pascal
unit myUnit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes;

type
  TmyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FStoppingCount: integer;

  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure ProcessIT();

  public
    { Public declarations }

  published
    { Published declarations }

    property StoppingCount: integer read FStoppingCount write FStoppingCount default -1;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('myComponent', [TmyComponent]);
end;

procedure TmyComponent.ProcessIT();
begin
  for I := 0 to 1000 do
  begin
    DoSomething();
    if FStoppingCount = I then break;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Negative values work just fine. The problem is that you did not actually initialize `FStoppingCount` to -1, so it instead gets initialized to 0 when new instances of the component are created and have their memory initially zeroed out.

Simply declaring a non-zero `default` value on the `property` declaration is not enough. The `default` value is merely stored in the property's RTTI, and is used only for comparison purposes when the component is written to a DFM, and when displaying the property value in the Object Inspector. The `default` directive does not actually affect instances of the component in memory.  You have to explicitly set the value of `FStoppingCount` to match the `default` value. This is clearly stated in the documentation:

[Properties (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi))

> Note: Property values are not automatically initialized to the default value. That is, the default directive controls only when property values are saved to the form file, but not the initial value of the property on a newly created instance.

To fix your component, you need to add a constructor that initializes `FStoppingCount` to -1, eg:

```pascal
unit myUnit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes;

type
  TmyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FStoppingCount: integer;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure ProcessIT();
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override; // <-- ADD THIS!
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property StoppingCount: integer read FStoppingCount write FStoppingCount default -1;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('myComponent', [TmyComponent]);
end;

constructor TmyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FStoppingCount := -1; // <-- ADD THIS!
end;

procedure TmyComponent.ProcessIT();
begin
  for I := 0 to 1000 do
  begin
    DoSomething();
    if FStoppingCount = I then break;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: EMBT could finally implement the `default` initialization. Or at least add some feature to produce a matching `default` property values. It's annoying when one needs to do this manually with every change.

Comment: @TLama automating the initialization of default values would add overhead to object creation, which is probably why it was never implemented.

Comment: It would, but it's just confusing. One declares a `default` value (which effectively does nothing more than showing a non bold text in Object Inspector property item when this value differs from `default`). Why to have `default` directive at all then?

Comment: @TLama you do know what `default` actually does to DFM streaming, don't you? It is not just the Object Inspector that uses `default` values. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: I know. Just effectively for a developer (of course except RTTI) has no other practical meaning than showing that in OI. And it's called `default` which one can simply assume to be the default initialization value; which is not. Surely it's just my philosophical feeling of this directive, but I was personally confused of this too.

Comment: What overhead would be added? Either the compiler generates the code, or the programmer writes it.

Comment: @David, a few instructions (maybe unwanted) for object instantiation. For me, personally, it's not comfortable as I need to do the value initialization at object creation manually.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the compiler would have to generate a constructor if the author did not provide one. And if they did, do you expect the compiler to modify it? Or worse, the TPersistent/TComponent constructor would have to enumerate RTTI to see if any defaults need to be filled in at runtime. And you know how much overhead RTTI adds. Now imagine that over hundreds of component objects, and that adds up

Comment: @Remy, yes, but constructor code is generated by compiler anyway. EMBT could just add those lines setting default values (the name `default` is just confusing right now).

Comment: @TLama I could see that being feisable only if they introduced a new method call between `Create()` and `AfterConstruction()`, say `InitProperties()`, and that method was class-specific and efficient (ie, specific assignments to specific fields, nothing else). But considering that they chose a poor RTTI based way to deal with weak references, instead of using efficient class-specific tables, if they were to go RTTI for this feature, it could easily turn into another runtime nightmare.

Comment: RTTI, ok. But implementing this in general would not break anything (old projects), IMHO. If you were having a constructor setting the values, none of them would be affected. Compiler would generate constructor code only to set the values which were not modified inside. And I'm fairly sure it's not so difficult to do so.

Comment: What is annoying is that one must keep this in mind. That `default` is merely *informative* directive and does not do anything for developers *in general*.

Comment: There are a lot of declarations where you have to remember what they "really mean," this is just one of those. Personally, I do not want more initialization on all of the objects I'm creating. This is fully documented behavior: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Property_Overrides_and_Redeclarations

Comment: @Brandon, sure. And I'm aware of it. But what would happen if the object would be initialized with `default` value only if its value is not initialized in its constructor? Compiler can generate such code and IMHO would not lead to questions like this. Right now it does not emit even any warning (like for example for uninitialized function result).

Comment: I don't see the need. At the moment you want to inform the compiler what the default value is and type "default," you also write the initialization of the default value where you believe it is appropriate to do so. There are a million improvements they should make to the compiler before contemplating this change, in my opinion.

Comment: @TLama And how exactly would you determine if the value hasn't been already initialized in constructor? I guess you could go and check constructor code in order to see if it contains some code that is writing some data to that value? But the problem is that you would have to do this for constructor of your class then constructor of your class parent class and its parent and so on all the way to TPresistant class. Also how would you handle cases where initialization code for that value is in a conditional clause? There is no way to avoid masive overhead using such kind of checking.

Comment: Any way after thinking a little more about TLama suggestion I actually think that on modern Delphi versions that support inline variable declaration that also allows setting initial value to that variable during its declaration that this could actually be done now. Now the question is whether it is feasible as it could potentially break backward compatibility and cause legacy programs to act differently.

Comment: @SilverWarior AFAIK, the new inline variable initialization feature doesn't work for class members, though.

Comment: @Silver, compiler just knows. How do you think it emits warning about uninitialized variables? If it found one, in constructor, with `default` value, let initialize it. What's the problem? Or at least say, "this property value is not initialized".

Comment: @TLama The compiler can emit an "uninitialized variable" warning only for local variables. Global variables and class member variables are never uninitialized.

Comment: @Remy, I know, but would that technically be a problem? Come on. Compiler knows about local and global variables pretty well.

Comment: @TLama If compiler `Just knows` as you say why then the warning says `Variable might not get initialized` instead `Variable will not get initialized`? In order to `Just know` the compiler would have to be able to generate a complete flow-graph of your code covering any possible scenarios but it can't. In fact I don't know of any program that would be able to build a full flow-graph od Delphi (Object Pascal) code. If you know of such program please do let me know as it would come in handy to me.

Comment: @Silver, class fields are always initialized, so the compiler knows about them. Why they say such warning for local variables I don't know (in the end they could emit it every time a local variable appears). About the flow-graph I don't know either, sorry.